# The mysterious widgets.map file

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, hcl

I am working on an HCL Commerce project and I receive this error when I load cart page locally:

> File not found: /MyWebExtSitesSAS/javascript/widgets.map

I cannot find anywhere in the web references for `widgets.map`. Can you describe me what is this file used for, and if I can ignore this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repost the answer in the comment by @disinfor because it answered my question

> You can ignore that. A map file is used for debugging purposes. When
> you minify code, e.g. js, css, etc. it obviously becomes hard to read
> to find any errors. The map file is used by a browser to show where in
> the original, unminified code the error is coming from.